# React Native - if/else infinite loop with useEffect

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this funciotn that perfectly works but at the end goes in an infinite loop.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if (!isReady) {
          const prepTimer = () => {
            let {eventDate} = {
              eventDate: moment.duration().add({
                minutes: 0,
                seconds: 4,
              }),
            };

            let count = 1;

            const x = setInterval(
              (function x() {
                count = count + 1;

                if (eventDate <= 0) {
                  clearInterval(x);

                  setPreparationOver(true);
                  setIsReady(true);
                  console.log('PREP STOPED');

                } else {
                  eventDate = eventDate.subtract(1, 's');

                  console.log('PREP COUNTDOWN', eventDate);
                }
                return x;
              })(),
              1000,
            );
          };
          prepTimer();
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }, []);
```

I have other functions like that but without the problem.
Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: You are updating the isReady state `setIsReady(true);` and also it is added in the dependency array of useEffect. 
So every time the isReady state is updated, it will fire this useEffect.

Comment: I know it I tried to remove it but it doesn't change

Comment: Can you replicate this on the sandbox or any other platform ?